# CodeIgniter cookie setter issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

The following doesn't set the cookie in codeigniter.

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
if (!$this->input->cookie('xx'))
{
    //Cookie not set, first visit
    $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'xx',
        'value'  => '1',
        'expire' => (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
        'path'   => '/',
        'prefix' => '',
        'secure' => TRUE
    );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
}
```

Checked the browser and even used the vardump($this->input->cookie('xx')); to get the result as false.

Comment: Use `if($this->input->cookie('cookiename')!=''){
            //exists
        }`  Check -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425066/check-if-cookie-exists-in-codeigniter

Comment: As per the document, 
(http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/input.html), the cookie('cookiename') would return false, if not found. And that's the response I am getting. The cookie is not set.

Comment: Try the basic usage in order to identify the problem: `$cookie = array(    'name'   => 'xx',
    'value'  => '1',
    'expire' => '86500');` . Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the secure from the array

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
if (!$this->input->cookie('xx'))
{
    //Cookie not set, first visit
    $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'xx',
        'value'  => '1',
        'expire' => (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
        'path'   => '/',
        'prefix' => ''
    );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
} // This may work
```

Answer (score 0):

Http connection was used and hence the cookie wouldn't be set if the variable 'secure' was set to true.
[Codeigniter uses setcookie() to set the value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

So removing the secure value successfully set the cookie and could get the value